# Update array properties dynamically in Vue 3 composition API when route param changes

Tags: vue.js

My component (Vue 3 with composition API + script setup) has a property `linkList`. This shall be updated whenever the route param `id` changes.

#### Example

When calling this component on `/user/1`, then `linkList` shall look like this:

```
{id: 1, name: 'foo'},
{id: 1, name: 'bar'}
```

This is my current code:

```js
<script setup>

const route = useRoute();
const idRouteParam = computed(() => route.params.id);

const linkList = [
{
  id: idRouteParam,
  name: 'foo',
},
{
  id: idRouteParam,
  name: 'bar',
}
];

watch(
  idRouteParam,
  () => {
    console.log(idRouteParam);
  },
  { immediate: true },
);

</script>
```

The problem is: `linkList` is only updated after the page is refreshed, i.e. the component is re-created. When `idRouteParam` changes (example: `/user/2`), then `linkList` has the original values from user 1. I thought that I could update it in the watcher but I guess I'm missing some piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `linkList` should be also defined as a computed property :

```js
const linkList = computed(()=>[
{
  id: idRouteParam,
  name: 'foo',
},
{
  id: idRouteParam,
  name: 'bar',
}
]);
```

Comment: OMG, sure... sometimes I'm thinking way too complicated 

Comment: sure, if a reactive property X is used as dependency in Y, Y should be a computed property